# HTML Responsive Image Grid Gallery Space Between images

Tags: javascript, html, css, image

I use the image gallery below.
https://tympanus.net/Development/AnimatedResponsiveImageGrid/

I want to space between the two pictures.

If I put a div between the li and a elements, javascript will not find that a element. The height of the a elements inside the div 0.

I tried to modify CSS with padding, margin properties, but I was not successful.
I used the background-size: containt, to position the images well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this `background-size` and remove or comment `background-color: #333;`

```
.ri-grid ul li a {
    ...
    background-size: calc(100% - 5px) !important;
    /* background-color: #333; */
    ...
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

add `background-size: calc(100% - 10px);` to `.ri-grid ul li a` element.
`10px` represent the space between each picture. You'll maybe need to change the background color of `<li>` and `<a>` to have a nice result.

Comment: It looks like something is missing in your answer.

Comment: yes, I edited my answer. But if you add background-size as I said, it'll works normally

Comment: Perfect! Thank you!